# R Programming - Error

Tags: r

I am unable to execute any instruction in R. Getting below error.

> Error in library("colorout") : there is no package called "colorout"

Also trying to execute: `Rscript.exe -e ".libPaths()"`

**Warning message:**

> package 'plyr' was built under R version 3.5.1 Error
>   in sys.source(".my_custom_functions.r", envir = custom_env) :
>   '.my_custom_functions.r' is not an existing file

Comment: You're trying to call a package that you don't have installed.

Comment: `git clone https://github.com/jalvesaq/colorout.git` ;
`R CMD INSTALL colorout` ; This package is only for MacOS or Linux, for windows its not available, you can also use devtools::install_github command to install this as well

Comment: That code is not to be done through R but through the shell. Probably best if you do the following instead: First, run `install.packages("devtools")` to install the devtools package, then use a function from that package by running `devtools::install_github("jalvesaq/colorout")` to install it.

Comment: For the second bit, it may be some code in your `~/.Rprofile` file that's calling the nonexistent file. And it looks like your R itself may be older than the packages, so updating is probably the first order of business.

Comment: Let me elaborate my problem: I am trying to build a site. but when I execute below instruction I am getting the error :

Comment: > library(blogdown)
> build_site()
Rendering content/post/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown.Rmd
Error in library("colorout") : there is no package called 'colorout'
Execution halted
Error in render_page(f) : 
  Failed to render 'content/post/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown.Rmd'

Comment: Thanks alistaire. it got resolved. but still the first problem exists. I mentioned the scenario above.

Comment: I tried remove.packages("colorout") but it gives package
Error in remove.packages : there is no package called ‘colorout’
but still the error pops up. unable to execute any instructions

Comment: There you go, you have no package called colorout. What's the problem? The package was removed from CRAN so `install.packages` will not work, and as PKumar noted, it's linux-ish only.

Comment: But why I am getting the error to execute other instruction ? 
> build_site()
Rendering content/post/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown.Rmd
Error in library("colorout") : there is no package called 'colorout'
Execution halted
Error in render_page(f) : 
  Failed to render 'content/post/2015-07-23-r-rmarkdown.Rmd'



why it is block to run other instruction. Is my R got corrupted ?

Comment: it turns out that I have library(colorout) inside ~/.Rprofile, when I updated R, this broke the colorout package and caused a lot of package installation failure.. good point here.